# Multiple Items RadioButtons Groups

Tags: php, html, radio-button

There is form with a list of items created dynamically in PHP, each has it's id(I mean database id, not the element's).
Each item has two radiobuttons (Good,Bad).
Is there a way to get in PHP an array of all items that are Bad and all item that are Good as if I was using checkboxes with names good[] and bad[]  and value="id" for each item.

Is there a way to make this with radiobuttons?

```
<form action="some.php" method="post">
    item 1: <br/>
    <input type="radio"/>Leave<br/>
    <input type="radio"/>Delete<br/>
    item 2: <br/>
    <input type="radio"/>Leave<br/>
    <input type="radio"/>Delete<br/>
</form>
```

Comment: Show your code would be more help

Comment: That's the problem. I tried to write the code, but my question is about the basic logic of the elements to provide such functionality

Comment: So can you show what your form look like?

Comment: done. the very basic, just to show the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't quite do it like you would with checkboxes.

Instead you need to accept all the name=""'s of the radiogroups and loop through them, building your own array in PHP after accepting the form.

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="good" /> Good<br />
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="bad" /> bad
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="good" /> Good<br />
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="bad" /> bad
</form>

<?php
$questions = array('question1', 'question2');
foreach($questions as $q) {
    if(isset($_POST[$q])) {
        switch($_POST[$q]) {
            case 'good':
                $good += 1;
                break;
            case 'bad':
                $bad += 1;
                break;
            default:
                // invalid value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean to pass through all the POST array items? Isn't it rather insecure?

Comment: How secure it is depends on your handling of the submitted data. But the point is, you can't group radio items like how you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You could make form like below:

```
<form action="some.php" method="post">
    <?php foreach ($ids as $i => $id) : ?>
    item <?php echo $i+1 ?>: <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="item[<?php echo $id ?>]" value="good"/>Leave<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="item[<?php echo $id ?>]" value="bad"/>Delete<br/>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

Then in `some.php`, `$_POST['item']` will give you an array like below:

```
array(
    'item_id1' => 'good',
    'item_id2' => 'bad',
    .....
)
```